# Set Environment Variable for .NET 5 Azure Function ServiceBusTrigger connection string programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

To preface, I know that the connection string comes from the Configuration on the Azure Portal / local.settings.json, and that it's an environment variable you can access with the following:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Name", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

I am trying to set the ServiceBusTrigger connection string from the appsettings.json.
I have added an appsettings.json file following [this blog on how to do it.](https://www.garyjackson.dev/posts/dotnet-isolated-azure-function-appsettings-secrets/) I am able to access settings from the appsettings.json file, however in the Program.cs when I try to use the following to set the environment variable:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration(c => 
{
  var config = c.SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
              .AddEnvironmentVariables()
              .Build();
  // Setting the Environment Variable for the connection string
  Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(config["ConnectionString:Name"], config["ConnectionString:Value"]);
})
```

where "Name" is what's passed to the Connection in the function, and "Value" is the connection string, I get the following error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'Name' is missing or empty.

The Connection I'm talking about:

```
public async Task Run(ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "Name")] string myQueueItem, FunctionContext) { // Some Implementation }
```

I am trying to avoid setting the connection string "Name" in the App Configuration on the Azure portal. Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

- When you set the variable by `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`, it will not show in application setting. But we can use it by `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` as expected.
- `SetEnvironmentVariable(String,String)` Creates, modifies, or deletes an environment variable stored in the current process.
- Although the solution you mentioned is not so good, but it can implement your requirement. The adverse effect is **when you restart the function app, the variables will be lost**.

For more information on `SetEnvironmentVariable`, please refer this [MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=net-6.0#definition)